# Auto decoding htmlspecialhars on output

Tags: php, codeigniter

The CI db library automatically converts my data into htmlspecialchars. I want it to be automatically decoded during output. Is it possible? I don't want to end up changing every `$row->column` to `htmlspecialchars_decode($row->column)`.

Comment: why don't you use foreach loop ?

Comment: This is about putting htmspecialchars_decode in every column in every view. For rows loops are always used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI DB classes don't do anything like that. You most likely have `$config['global_xss_filtering']` enabled ...

Just disable that setting; it's deprecated since CodeIgniter 3.0.0, so you shouldn't be using it anyway.